# JupyterLab import csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-lab

I'm a newbie to programming going through Anaconda Nucleus with the goal of learning Python and Pandas (I love Excel and want to take things to next level).
I'm struggling to import a csv file?
Using JupyterLab and MacBook Pro [Ventura 13.0].

Here are my first few lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/keith/Documents/python_test2/RI_ppp_loans_state.csv')
```

I am getting below error:

```
FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [291. in <cell line: 1>(
-> 1 df = pd.read_csv('/Users/keith/Documents/python_test2/RI_ppp_loans_state.csv'
```

I am copying the Full file_path on my MacBook and pasting it into line 2 of code above.
I have been searching for solutions and have tried adding `r'` before the file path.
I've also tried double `//` vs a single `/`.

In addition, I've moved the file to different places on my Mac with no luck.
Any suggestions ?   Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the file is readable (use `ls -l`)?  Assuming it is, try eliminating JupyterLab by putting those two lines into a python script and running it directly using python in the same directory.  If it still fails, replace the fullpath with just `"RI_ppp_loans_state.csv"` (since it's in the same directory).  To check if the file name has unexpected encoding or characters you could do `ls RI* | od -c` in that directory.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a possibility you must be running the code from different working directory. In that case you need to use `abspath`-

```
import os
file_path = os.path.abspath('/Users/keith/Documents/python_test2/RI_ppp_loans_state.csv')
```

And then you need to pass the `abspath` to `read_csv` -

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

You also need to `check the permissions` on that path/file